# ICE servers(google stuns) worked for 8 times behind NAT but since then not working but works locally. Why?

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, p2p, peer, conference

**Please refer to these screenshots**
[Image[Behind NAT]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrrO9.png) -- [Image[Same Network]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8teQ9.png) -- [Image[Stuns]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTP87.png)

Guys I have implemented step-05 code sample from WebRTC's codelab.
I have provided 5 google's stun servers and fortunately the code worked as expected(not using TURN).
I was able to form p2p comm. between two clients behind NAT and I tested thoroughly everything was working fine behind NAT !! but after few more attempts of trial the same code and ICE server configuration stopped responding. I am not able to see remote stream anymore.Even after restarting droplet and my networking devices.

The strange part is that when I again switch to my WiFi(local network) then the streams start coming.
Since I have not changed the code and tested the system behind NAT for 8 times,not able to catch the problem.
What should be the reason ? I am sure it's a ICE Server issue **either google stuns flagged my host(app. server ip)** or a **premium stun/turn server is required**.

***please advise .. what you think !***!

Code reference: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web/#7

Architecture:

Signaling host: NodeJs https(self signed) running at port 8080 at DigitalOcean

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a droplet, I would try following:

Use one (1) Google Stun-Server and for testing, setup an instance of coturn on the droplet and fill in the credentials in your config. It's a 10 minute thing and after that you will find out that this might have caused the error.